# Which CMS should be used to build web site using PostreSQL, can latest WordPress used

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, web, content-management-system, drupal-7

I’m looking for a way to build web site which uses PostreSQL to store web pages and allow users to modify them.

Admin user should able to create and changed pages using html editor from browser.
Site runs in Debian Squeeze x64 VPS using Apache. There are already Mono 2.8 and PostreSQL 9.1 applications running in this VPS.

There is no PHP installed but it can probably installed if software requires this.
Maintaining MySql in addition to PostreSQL in same server may be not reasonable so I'm looking for a way to use Postgres.

CMS should provide nice dark theme for web site so that web designer is not required for this.

WordPress PostreSQL plugin page http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/
states this this plugin is not compatible with latest wordpress.
Also this plugin is not updated for a while.
Joomla! does not run in Postgres DBMS.
Drupal 7 seems to support it but comparing to WordPress Drupal usage is smaller.

There are mono ASP.NET applications running in this site so using some ASP.NET CMS seems best.
Latest Orchad does not run in Mono and PostgreSQL.

How to use latest WordPress with PostreSQL 9.1 ?
Which CMS software is best for  PostreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maintaining MySql in addition to PostgeSql in same server may be not reasonable

I'm not a professional sysadmin, but I'm not sure that's true. Here is a Server Fault question where it is claimed that operating both in parallel works fine: https://serverfault.com/questions/35934/installing-and-running-mysql-and-postgresql-8-4-side-by-side

mySQL is the quasi industry standard in the PHP world, so the biggest products all use it, and in the case of WP (and most others), it's the only database suppored. Adding Postgres support as a requirement seriously limits your options, so installing mySQL side-by-side with Postgres may be a good idea.

That said, Drupal is a perfectly fine, well-esteemed CMS framework and if its features and architecture work for your purposes, there is no reason not to choose it.

Comment: I agree, and the reverse is true.  If you're installing apps that were primarily developed for postgresql trying to make them run on mysql can also be painful.  Unless you need absolute maximum performance from a database server, there's usually no issue running both on the same server.