# Can Wordpress CMS use other DBMS instead of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, odbc

I have a question, Can Wordpress CMS use other DBMS instead of MySQL? Do WordPress use ODBC connection or MySQL connection?

Thanks for Information that you give me.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545723/which-cms-should-be-used-to-build-web-site-using-postresql-can-latest-wordpress the answer is "not really".

Comment: try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6410/are-there-any-plans-for-wordpress-to-support-databases-other-than-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible.
Using [these plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdo-for-wordpress/) to using SQLite instead of MySQL, I tested it and worked correctly